# How to populate an array with input from text field

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have been trying to populate a string array with data from an edit text
but all it keeps giving me errors it says the a string type is required and i am quite new to android and don't know what that is and it also says that it cannot resolve method add

```
package com.android.beez.bored;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button save;
Button pushMe;
TextView textOne;
String hobby = new String();
EditText txt;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtinput);
    save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnsave);
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String getInput =  txt.getText().toString();
            hobby.add(getInput);
        }


    });
    pushMe = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pushMe);
    pushMe.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int rando = (int)(Math.random()*3);
            textOne.setText(hobby[rando]);
        }
    });

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`hobby` is a `String` and `String`s don't have a method called `add` in Java.

You should change `hobby`'s type from `String` to `String[]` because there is a `hobby[rando]` in the code that indicates `hobby`'s type must be `String[]`

Comment: i want it to be a string array not array list so what must i change

Comment: after  i changed the line to 'hobby += getInput' it still says on the 'textOne.setText(hobby[rando]);' line thai an array type is expected

Comment: yes and you should change it to `textOne.setText(hobby);`

Comment: then what about the 'rando' int i want it implemented how will i go about it

Comment: like this 'String hobby = new String[];'

Comment: `String[] hobby = new String[] `

Comment: it says array initialzer expected

Comment: sorry to keep disturbing you like this but this is very urgent

Answer (score 0):

As the first answer indicated there is no add() method in the Java String class. But you can use concat() instead, it concatenates the specified string to the end of the current string.  So change
 `hobby.add(getInput);`
       with 
`hobby = hobby.concat(getInput);` 
without affecting the remaining of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you declared your "array" as a string.

In my opinion, since you want to be able to dynamically `add` stuff the array, an `ArrayList<String>` is more suitable.

Change the declaration of `hobby` to this:

```
ArrayList<String> hobbies = new ArrayList<>();
```

Another thing that you need to change is in the on click listener for the `pushMe` button.

Change this:

```
textOne.setText(hobby[rando]);
```

to this:

```
textOne.setText(hobbies.get(rando));
```

because the `[]` syntax is for accessing arrays, not array lists.

Anyway, your code seems like you want to access a random item in the array list and display it in a text view. `Math.random() * 3` won't work if you want to do this.

Try this instead:

```
Random r = new Random();
int rando = r.nextInt(hobbies.size());
textOne.setText(hobbies.get(rando));
```